# How to display menu items from database using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sqlite

Hi i'm writing a menu list with css jquery and javascript : i want to get the menu items from a database

js code:

```
  var selectAllStatement = "SELECT * FROM Contacts";
           function  findAll(){
       var name;
     db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) {
    dataset = result.rows;
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
          item = dataset.item(i);
          name = item['firstName'] }
                   });
                                  });

              }
```

html file:

```
    <section id="popupAccordeon" class="hide">

<div id="popup-bg">
</div>

     <div id="popup-box">   

    <ul class="niveau1">
        <li><a href="">  Players Name</a>
                <ul class="niveau2">

        <li><a href="http://www.rankspirit.com"> </a></li> // this are items i want to get them from table Contacts

            </ul>

  </section>
```

Comment: are you getting some sort of error message with your code? I would agree with MatuDuke about using PHP or similar though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some server-side languaje such as PHP, C#, Java, Ruby, etc.
It depends on your server.

Comment: i can get all table rows in the dataset but i don't know how to put it in the menu list items this is my problem , every thing is fine with requesting the database

Comment: How are you retrieving your dataset? Are you using some server-side programing language? Which one? Could you put some code of it?

Comment: i'm using SQLite  here's the code :  var selectAllStatement = "SELECT * FROM Contacts";
           function  findAll(){
       var name;
     db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) {
    dataset = result.rows;
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
          item = dataset.item(i);
          name = item['firstName'] }
                   });
                                  });

              }

Comment: Unless you're using som JavaScript code to access databases (this will be very weird), you CAN NOT access any database from JavaScript.
If you want to retrieve data from SQLite, you will have to write some PHP code (just to name one language), and call that .php file from JavaScript (using Ajax).

Comment: i found this link i trisd it and it's very usefull [http://developpeur.orange.tn/developper-ensemble/tutoriels/tutoriels/phonegap-sqlite][1]


  [1]: http://developpeur.orange.tn/developper-ensemble/tutoriels/tutoriels/phonegap-sqlite

Comment: This only works with Webkit browser engine and is only for client-side database.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript, CSS and HTML works on the frontend of the sites. These files are downloaded to the browser and they run in the browser's scope.

Database resides in the server. You would need a server side language for interacting with database and generating the necessary html to be sent to the server.